# Prevent the user from turning on/off GPS, wifi, internet buttons in android form notification bar

Tags: android

I am looking for solution to my problem for 2 days. I searched a lot but not found.
I have developed a GPS traking application in andorid. What I want is while running my app, app will block the user from switch on /off the GPS, Wifi,Internet toggle buttons on the notification area.

Any body have a solution? Please help

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  The user should be in control of their data connections.  I think this is impossible, since to do so would be a bad thing, but even if you could, you should not do it.

Comment: But I have seen such a feature in some of the App locker application